# MS Access - Converting Date Format for Short Text

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a .mdb Access database with a table `Door Activity Log` . In it, there's a column named `Door Activity Log Date` of type `Short Text`. Currently, its format is in American date format (mm/dd/yyyy).

How would I convert/manipulate the date (I'm guessing Short Text is just string) in Access so that it becomes `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: Can use Format() function. `Format([Door Activity Log Date], "dd/mm/yyyy")`. The result is a string, not a true date. Doesn't actually change how value is stored. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't change how the value is stored? It's not a `Date/Time` column, it is `Short Text` .Actually, I'm trying to import the table from Access to an identical table in SQL Server. Only that the one in SQL Server is in `dd/mm/yyyy` .

Comment: Doesn't matter what the field type is. Formatting doesn't change the original stored value in Access. That was probably an irrelevant comment. The value saved to SQLServer will be the string resulting from the Format() calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with with VBA

```
Private Sub dateFormattingConvert()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim oldDate As String
Dim newDate As String
Dim year As String
Dim month As String
Dim day As String
Dim fullString As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Door Activity Log")

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        Debug.Print (rs![Door Activity Log Date])
        oldDate = rs![Door Activity Log Date]
        year = Right(oldDate, 4)
        month = Left(oldDate, 2)
        day = Mid(oldDate, 4, 2)
        fullString = day & "/" & month & "/" & year

        rs.Edit
        rs![Door Activity Log Date] = fullString
        rs.Update

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "No more records."
End If

MsgBox "Finished"

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates should always be stored as *dates*, not text.

So, create a new field in the table, *ActivityLogDate*, and fill it with a query like this:

```
Update 
    [Door Activity Log]
Set 
    ActivityLogDate = DateSerial(Mid([Activity Log Date], 7, 4), Mid([Activity Log Date], 1, 2), Mid([Activity Log Date], 4, 2))
```